# How can one interface satin?

Tags: sewing

Satin is notoriously difficult to work with, from puckering to fraying, from slipping to sliding.

Interfacing a fabric often allows for more structure, and often makes for an easier time sewing with said fabric.

Unfortunately these satin and interfacing don't combine well. Iron-on interfacing often requires an iron-setting of two dots, with satin only allowing ironing at a single dot heat.

How can one best 'stabilize' satin to make it easier to work with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple: **You use sew-in interfacing**.

Not all interfacing requires an iron; a very wide range of sew-in options exist and can be used with satin to give the completed garment more structure. Do note that **the purpose of interfacing is to provide structure, not to make fabric easier to handle**.

**If you're looking for a way to stiffen the fabric while working with it**, but maintain the usual structure of satin in the completed garment, you can try using a washable glue or starch, or sewing/gluing a bit of wash-a-way embroidery stabilizer in place; these will be removed by washing the garment, leaving you with only satin.

You can also sandwich your seams between pieces of wash-a-way to help guide it through the machine without slipping, and using sewing clips instead of pins to hold your pieces together. Wash-a-way is very easily removed, and clips won't contribute to puckering or fraying while providing a greater area of contact with the fabric for stabilization.

Answer (score 1):

You can flatline the garment - cut the same pattern pieces from a fabric that will give you better handling characteristics of the fabric, place the flatlining fabric pattern pieces next to the fashion fabric with wrong sides together, and sew the pattern treating the fashion fabric plus flatlining fabric combo as if it were a single piece of fabric.